# JDom2 SAXBuilder - Random XML Structure error with valid XML file

Tags: java, xml, sax, jdom

I wrote an application working as linux daemon that is parsing an XML file of around 100 MB.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder;
import org.jdom2.output.Format;
import org.jdom2.output.XMLOutputter;
import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.Element;
import org.jdom2.JDOMException;

public class MyReader {


    private Document doc;
    private Element rootNode;


    public MyReader(String Filename) {      
        try {
        doc = (Document) new SAXBuilder().build(new File(Filename));
        rootNode = doc.getRootElement();    

        } catch ( NullPointerException | NumberFormatException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JDOMException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm processing with this method around 14 files for week, from time to time one of the file fails producing this stacktrace:

```
org.jdom2.input.JDOMParseException: Error on line 15410 of document file:/home/files/new/100.xml: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
    at org.jdom2.input.sax.SAXBuilderEngine.build(SAXBuilderEngine.java:228)
    at org.jdom2.input.sax.SAXBuilderEngine.build(SAXBuilderEngine.java:277)
    at org.jdom2.input.sax.SAXBuilderEngine.build(SAXBuilderEngine.java:264)
    at org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:1116)
    at com.scoobydoo.files.MyReader.<init>(MyReader.java:38)
    at application.Daemon.checkNewImportFiles(Daemon.java:225)
    at application.Daemon.startApplication(Daemon.java:68)
    at application.Daemon.run(Daemon.java:36)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/home/files/new/100.xml; lineNumber: 15410; columnNumber: 35; XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:400)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1437)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.endEntity(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:904)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.endEntity(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:563)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.endEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1399)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(XMLEntityScanner.java:1811)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.skipChar(XMLEntityScanner.java:1460)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2824)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:118)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at org.jdom2.input.sax.SAXBuilderEngine.build(SAXBuilderEngine.java:217)
    ... 8 more
```

The strange thing is that if I try to import the file a second time this is imported without any error.

Naturally i already checked the file and validated it with xmllint and it doesn't report any problem.

My guessing is that SAXBuilder().build() open an InputStream to the file and for some reason is truncated, do you have any idea how to check this or about any other problem that could be causing this?

Thanks in advance to everyone!

## *************************Update*************************

Hi Guys,
i had a kind of illumination this morning, the file is being processed follow by an upload from a user. My guessing is that the process is starting to read the file when this is not completely uploaded yet, so not being the file complete it is failing.

This match with the problem and with the fact that trying to read the file afterwards is complete because at the "human check" moment the upload is complete.

I did a change to verify that the file is completely uploaded before trying to process that (don't know why i didn't though to it before), will let you know if the problem come out again.

Thanks!

Comment: jdom2 consumes a huge amount of memory for 100mb file... is that an issue for you?

Comment: Hi vtd-xml-author, thanks for your answer :) I got a server with 4 GB of memory just for this, and the maximum amount of concurrent files to process is 1 so it should not be a problem.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? Is it upload completion related?